# How to Search For Excel (2003) Files which Contain Macros on Server?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, microsoft-excel-2003

How can I search for Excel files that contain VBA code, are there any efficient ways to do this?

The way I'm thinking of would be to use vbscript and recursively search through the directory, open the excel file, and then search for VBA code... is there a better way?

I'm searching alot of files and would like to maximize my efficiency.

### Update:

Okay the Answer for this question is listed  [here at Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140030/how-to-determine-quickly-which-sheets-have-macros-in-excel-workbook)

Comment: Why not search for .xlsm files?

Comment: You should have asked this at Stack OverFlow instead as you require a programming solution.

Comment: Yah it's Excel 2003 Files.

Comment: See : http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2012/04/12/check-if-an-excel-file-has-a-macro/